# Pentax K1000 settings question

Tags: film, camera-settings, 35mm, pentax, pentax-k1000

I have a Pentax K1000 and 400 film that I’ll be using with it. I wanted to take some photos of my newborn in the hospital and was curious of the recommended settings I should use. Really want these pictures to come out perfect. I have a battery but the meter still doesn’t work so needed help with settings.

Comment: My humble opinion: this is one time event and if you want good photos just rent a photographer. Or use your phone.

Comment: Nobody can tell you "perfect settings" without actually measuring the light. I second Romeo's suggestion - why are you "experimenting" if the event is so important? Play safe now, there'll be plenty of opportunity for experimentation later as your child grows.

Comment: Or, get ballpark exposure settings from your phone and [bracket](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/54760)

Comment: You should practice before the event rather than thinking asking for settings will get it right.  Go where you will take the photos, or as close (in light, not location) as you can get and try things.  Keep careful records of what you do for each frame.  Now you will know what works.  It is silly to think a "good camera" (and we are talking here of an ancient film camera) is the secret to good photos.  Phone cameras work hard to get good photos in a wide range of situations, including this one.  They fail in tough lighting or when you want a narrow field of view, not here.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a hand-held exposure meter if you have one. An exposure meter app is an option too, but it should be checked against another hand-held meter or a camera, because on some phones it works well and on others it doesn't.

However, if you really need "pictures to come out perfect", you should find a camera with a working meter, preferably AF (if you don't have enough experience with MF lenses), and try it before the important event. If you expect hospital lighting to be dim, an external flash would be useful too.